# How to end my main function?

Tags: c

I want to end my main function if the user enters a value out of range. For some reason, this doesn't seem to work.

```
fscanf(stdin, "%d", &T);

if(!(T >= 1 || T <=500)) exit(0);
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your statement is always true for any number, and after `!` always false. Just think about it.

Comment: @Igor You're right, I just realized it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any value of `T`, `T >= 1 || T <=500` becomes `true`. This is because each and every value is either greater than `1` **or**  less than `500`. If `T` is `0` then it is less than `500` and if `T` is `501` then it is greater than `1`. This results in `!(T >= 1 || T <=500` to be `false` always.

Try this instead

```
if( T < 1 || T > 500 ) exit(0);
```

or you can correct your logic as

```
if(!(T >= 1 && T <=500)) exit(0);
```

Comment: @Tom Fenech - Nope, it is not. The OP's original condition doesn't make sense (consider what happens, if you pass a `T` with a value of `501`). The `||` in the OP's condition is likely to be wrong.

Comment: @TomFenech No, the logically equivalent form needs to turn `||` into `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's distribute the `!` (De Morgan's law) and it should be more clear why:

```
 if(!(T >= 1) && !(T <=500)) exit(0);
```

then

```
 if(T < 1 && T > 500) exit(0);
```

In other words, the condition is never satisfied.

You want simply

```
 if(T < 1 || T > 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the value you entered is between 1 and 500. Try printing the scanned value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(T <= 1 || T >=500)) 
    return 0;
```

for this you need to start your main function with an integer return value, like

```
int main() //instead of void main() or just main()
```